# Need of Localisation? and Intuition.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was going through some material related to localisation of rings. I am having a trouble with understanding why it is needed. I just see it as a way to create more rings but I have no idea what is special about the $S^{-1}A$ where $S$ is a multiplicative closed set and 
$R$ is the ring. My knowledge of tensors if very limited.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Well, don't you think it is interesting how Q is obtained from Z? This construction is a generalisation